# Firebug reporting CSS syntax error at beginning of external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, syntax-error

Firebug complains about a syntax error in one of my external CSS files and always blames the first line: 
`SyntaxError: syntax error`

For testing purposes I tried to comment out and remove the first rule completely, but the error is still displayed for the next rule. All style sheets in the file are ignored.

[image: screenshot of Firebug error message]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually this is a JavaScript syntax error, not a CSS problem. This happens when absent-mindedly copy-pasting HTML tags and including a CSS file using a script tag. **D'oh!**

Actually, the browser tries to parse the CSS content as JavaScript, which of course does not work. The solution is simple:

```
<script src="style.css"></script> <!-- won't work -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> <!-- better :) -->
```

Comment: This situation just happened to me, and just like you wrote : some absent-mindedly copy-paster ... <script instead of <link.